# Custom Linq-to-SQL MappingSource

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

I have a project which mixes compiled entity framework domain with dynamicly defined external databases. Users can supply the connection string, table name, and column names at run time to access an external system. I had previously been using dynamically generated SQL to access the external system (of course crafted with care to avoid SQL injection), and read the interested tables into `DataTable`'s and materialized these into POCO's.

Now, 90% of my views used `IQueryable` objects to inspect the structure of DB queries and format / page / manipulate the views efficiently. This allowed me to do a fair amount of work with the query *before* executing it. For views which involve records from external systems, I just gritted my teeth and used `IEnumerable.AsQueryable()`.

I'd very much like to use a different solution. I'm leaning toward Linq-to-SQL (I'm open to other suggestions), but I'm stuck at creating a dynamic `MappingSource`. Also, some columns are optional, and I don't know if Linq-to-SQL will blow up if I don't provide a mapping for every column, or not.

```
public class ExternalMappingSource : MappingSource
{
    public string[] KeyColumns { get; set; }

    public string NameColumn { get; set; }

    public string DescriptionColumn { get; set; }

    public string TimestampColumn { get; set; }

    protected override MetaModel CreateModel(Type dataContextType)
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any good resources on this online. How do I flush out this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the relevant structure up front (table and field values), you can feed in a custom mapping source based on that data without having the object beforehand. For me, for a different reason, I ended up using the XmlMappingSource object because it has a .FromXml() method you can use to feed in arbitrary Xml. You can get a feel for the structure of the Xml needed if you check out the mapping file produced by sqlmetal:

- open the VS Command Prompt (it’s in a Visual Studio Tools folder in the start menu).
- Change the directory to your project.
- Enter the command “sqlmetal /map:whatever.map /code yourlinqtosql.dbml”. This generates a whatever.map file with the formatted Xml.

Alter as needed programmatically to feed into the XmlMappingSource.FromXml() method. Then, you can create your context with the relevant connection string and the altered mapping source.

Comment: I've considered the `XmlMappingSource`, but I'd have to generate the XML on the fly. Generating the XML only to have it parsed in the very next line just seems wasteful. +1 for the suggestion, but I'd rather directly configure the 'MappingSource'.

Comment: Understood. Any way you cut it, you'll be manipulating the mapping more or less manually. :(

Comment: I eventually came to the decision that a custom `MappingSource` was going to take longer than my current release schedule allowed. For the time being, I'm going with your solution and saving the generated XML in the database to avoid having to recreate it every time I need to access the external system. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I'm sad you had to drop to a punt, but glad it'll work for you.